# Starting a large number of dependent process in async using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Problem: I've a DAG(Directed-acyclic-graph) like structure for starting the execution of some massive data processing on a machine. Some of the process can only be started when their parent data processing is completed cause there is multi level of processing. I want to use python multiprocessing library to handle all on one single machine of it as first goal and later scale to execute on different machines using Managers. I've got no prior experience with python multiprocessing. Can anyone suggest if it's a good library to begin with? If yes, some basic implementation idea would do just fine. If not, what else can be used to do this thing in python?

Example:

A -> B

B -> D, E, F, G

C -> D

In the above example i want to kick A & C first(parallel), after their successful execution, other remaining processes would just wait for B to finish first. As soon as B finishes its execution all other process will start.

P.S.: Sorry i cannot share actual data because confidential, though i tried to make it clear using the example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using processes and queues for things like this.

Like so:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from Queue import Empty as QueueEmpty
import time

#example process functions
def processA(queueA, queueB):
    while True:
        try:
            data = queueA.get_nowait()
            if data == 'END':
                break
        except QueueEmpty:
            time.sleep(2) #wait some time for data to enter queue
            continue
        #do stuff with data
        queueB.put(data)

def processA(queueB, _):
    while True:
        try:
            data = queueB.get_nowait()
            if data == 'END':
                break
        except QueueEmpty:
            time.sleep(2) #wait some time for data to enter queue
            continue
        #do stuff with data

#helper functions for starting and stopping processes
def start_procs(num_workers, target_function, args):
    procs = []
    for _ in range(num_workers):
        p = Process(target=target_function, args=args)
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    return procs

def shutdown_process(proc_lst, queue):
    for _ in proc_lst:
        queue.put('END')
    for p in proc_lst:
        try:
            p.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

queueA = Queue(<size of queue> * 3) #needs to be a bit bigger than actual. 3x works well for me
queueB = Queue(<size of queue>)
queueC = Queue(<size of queue>)
queueD = Queue(<size of queue>)

procsA = start_procs(number_of_workers, processA, (queueA, queueB)) 
procsB = start_procs(number_of_workers, processB, (queueB, None))  

# feed some data to processA
[queueA.put(data) for data in start_data]  

#shutdown processes
shutdown_process(procsA, queueA)
shutdown_process(procsB, queueB)

#etc, etc. You could arrange the start, stop, and data feed statements to arrive at the dag behaviour you desire
```

Comment: That's a good example. But considering the amount of dependencies the data can have, is it a good idea to have Queue? What i think is a Pool of workers should be better, any suggestions?

Comment: In the case of DAG, one process can have multiple parent process. It makes me doubt the validity of maintaining separate Queues for each process. It might not work correctly. Sometimes the program will have to wait for all parents to finish not just one.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to maintain a Manager list(shared among all process), and whenever we finish one process, for dependents we check the list if all other parents are finished or not and kick start if they are finished. If not we just close that process cause other process(parent) will start after finishing. Any idea or suggestion on this?

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, I would write some code that pools the results from several queues and then make sure that all the ingredients are there before shipping the data piece to the next queue. Just have to get creative and think outside of a singular process/queue line

Comment: My problem with the manager is that you would still have downtime waiting for every process to completely finish. It operates more waterfall-like than a true pipeline

Comment: From what i've tried now the best i can think of is what i said earlier. Downtime is okay, sine the process is actually executing. As long as multiple things can execute at the same time, i can get the optimization i need. Not really concerned if there's actually downtime caused by executing process.



Hmm i see, I think i need more investigation of the library. Not very much familiar with this. Just have to do it in python cause of compatibility. Thanks for the answer though.